# Geoserver WPS Process chaining

Tags: raster, geoserver, wps, jiffle

I am trying to chain ras:jiffle and ras:CoverageClassStats.
Both works well. The problem I think is with the result type of the jiffle calculation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
  xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:CoverageClassStats</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
            <ows:Identifier>ras:Jiffle</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:DataInputs>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
                  <wps:Body>
                    <wcs:GetCoverage xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 
          http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsAll.xsd" service="WCS" version="2.0.1">
                      <wcs:CoverageId>DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip</wcs:CoverageId>
                      <wcs:DimensionSlice>
                        <wcs:Dimension>time</wcs:Dimension>
                        <wcs:SlicePoint>2020-07-15T00:00:00.000Z</wcs:SlicePoint>
                      </wcs:DimensionSlice>
                      <wcs:format>image/geotiff</wcs:format>
                    </wcs:GetCoverage>
                  </wps:Body>
                </wps:Reference>
              </wps:Input>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>script</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Data>
                  <wps:LiteralData>uno = src[0];dos = src[1];tres = src[2];cuatro = src[3];cinco = src[4];seis = src[5];
                    siete = src[6];ocho = src[7];nueve = src[8];diez = src[9];once = src[10];doce = src[11];
                    trece = src[12];catorce = src[13];
                    dest = (ocho - cuatro) / (ocho + cuatro);</wps:LiteralData>
                </wps:Data>
              </wps:Input>
            </wps:DataInputs>
            <wps:ResponseForm>
              <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="image/tiff">
                <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
              </wps:RawDataOutput>
            </wps:ResponseForm>
          </wps:Execute>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>stats</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>mean</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>band</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>0</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>classes</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>1</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>method</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:LiteralData>NATURAL_BREAKS</wps:LiteralData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml">
      <ows:Identifier>results</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

And the response in Postman:

```
ras:CoverageClassStatscoverageClassStatsCalculates statistics from coverage values classified into bins/classes.Unrecognized request type net.opengis.wps10.impl.ExecuteTypeImpl@74614f (language: null, service: WPS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {})
```

GeoTools log:

```
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-04-21 17:01:56,260 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd
2021-04-21 17:01:56,262 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0: http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd ==> jar:file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wps-21.2.jar!/org/geotools/wps/wpsAll.xsd
2021-04-21 17:02:05,787 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,788 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,789 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,789 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,798 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,803 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,811 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - schemaLocation found: http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsAll.xsd
2021-04-21 17:02:05,831 DEBUG [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - Found override for http://www.opengis.net/wcs/2.0: http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/2.0/wcsAll.xsd ==> jar:file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-xsd-wcs-21.2.jar!/org/geotools/wcs/v2_0/wcsAll.xsd
2021-04-21 17:02:05,832 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,832 WARN [org.geotools.xsd.impl] - cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip' of element 'wcs:CoverageId' is not valid.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,834 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,834 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,834 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,834 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,838 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,838 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xlink:simpleAttrs' to a(n) 'attribute group' component.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,851 WARN [org.geoserver.wps] - cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip' of element 'wcs:CoverageId' is not valid.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,855 INFO [org.geoserver.wcs2_0.util] -  Examining encoded name DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip
2021-04-21 17:02:05,855 INFO [org.geoserver.wcs2_0.util] -  Checking coverage name DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip
2021-04-21 17:02:05,855 INFO [org.geoserver.wcs2_0.util] -  - Collecting layer DEMOS:ej_14_bands_zip
2021-04-21 17:02:05,859 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,862 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT distinct("ingestion") FROM "public"."ej_14_bands_zip"
2021-04-21 17:02:05,863 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,865 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LogicFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyIsBetween
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyIsBetween
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid",encode(ST_AsEWKB("the_geom"),'base64') as "the_geom","location","ingestion","elevation" FROM "public"."ej_14_bands_zip" WHERE ("ingestion" BETWEEN ? AND ? AND "ingestion" IS NOT NULL  AND "the_geom" && ST_GeomFromWKB(?, 32721) AND ST_Intersects("the_geom", ST_GeomFromWKB(?, 32721))) LIMIT 1
2021-04-21 17:02:05,868 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 1 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 2 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 3 = POLYGON ((-104804608.58375639 958015000840.3525, 4939270.697245682 958015000840.3593, -3189146.947964443 958238928756.631, -2784036.099205374 958302658989.9156, -104804608.58375639 958015000840.3525))
2021-04-21 17:02:05,869 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 4 = POLYGON ((-104804608.58375639 958015000840.3525, 4939270.697245682 958015000840.3593, -3189146.947964443 958238928756.631, -2784036.099205374 958302658989.9156, -104804608.58375639 958015000840.3525))
2021-04-21 17:02:05,870 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,872 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Reading mosaic from file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/DEMOS/ej_14_bands_zip/datastore.properties
2021-04-21 17:02:05,872 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Highest res 10.0 10.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,872 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Requested interpolation: javax.media.jai.InterpolationNearest@62711db0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,872 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Prepping to manage SortBy Clause
2021-04-21 17:02:05,873 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,874 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LogicFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid",encode(ST_AsEWKB("the_geom"),'base64') as "the_geom" FROM "public"."ej_14_bands_zip" WHERE ("the_geom" && ST_GeomFromWKB(?, 32721) AND "ingestion" <= ? AND "ingestion" IS NOT NULL  AND "ingestion" >= ?)
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 1 = POLYGON ((594520 8623800, 594520 8625810, 596140 8625810, 596140 8623800, 594520 8623800))
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 2 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,875 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 3 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,877 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,877 TRACE [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adjusted Requested Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0]
Requested raster dimension = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=162,height=201]
Corresponding raster source region = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=162,height=201]
Corresponding source Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0]
2021-04-21 17:02:05,877 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loading level 0 with subsampling factors 1 1
2021-04-21 17:02:05,877 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Prepping to manage SortBy Clause
2021-04-21 17:02:05,877 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog] - Index Loaded
2021-04-21 17:02:05,878 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,878 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting LogicFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.jdbc] - exporting PropertyName
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "fid",encode(ST_AsEWKB("the_geom"),'base64') as "the_geom","location","ingestion","elevation" FROM "public"."ej_14_bands_zip" WHERE ("the_geom" && ST_GeomFromWKB(?, 32721) AND "ingestion" <= ? AND "ingestion" IS NOT NULL  AND "ingestion" >= ?)
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 1 = POLYGON ((594520 8623800, 594520 8625810, 596140 8625810, 596140 8623800, 594520 8623800))
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 2 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,879 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 3 = 2020-07-15 00:00:00.0
2021-04-21 17:02:05,883 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Thread:pool-16-thread-11 Loading raster data for granuleDescriptor Description of a granuleDescriptor 
BBOX:       ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0]
file:       file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/DEMOS/ej_14_bands_zip/images/S2B_MSIL2A_20200715T140059_N0214_R067_T21LWG_20200715T162437_14BANDS.tif
gridToWorld:        PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 594525.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 8625805.0]]
Description of level 2
Description of a granuleDescriptor level
width:      162
height:     201
scaleX:     1.0
scaleY:     1.0
baseToLevelTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3]]
gridToWorldTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 594520.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 8625810.0]]


2021-04-21 17:02:05,884 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loading level 0 with source region: java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=162,height=201] subsampling: 1,1 for granule:file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/DEMOS/ej_14_bands_zip/images/S2B_MSIL2A_20200715T140059_N0214_R067_T21LWG_20200715T162437_14BANDS.tif
2021-04-21 17:02:05,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector] - We added the granule Description of a granuleDescriptor 
BBOX:       ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0]
file:       file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/DEMOS/ej_14_bands_zip/images/S2B_MSIL2A_20200715T140059_N0214_R067_T21LWG_20200715T162437_14BANDS.tif
gridToWorld:        PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 594525.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 8625805.0]]
Description of level 2
Description of a granuleDescriptor level
width:      162
height:     201
scaleX:     1.0
scaleY:     1.0
baseToLevelTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3]]
gridToWorldTransform:       PARAM_MT["Affine", 
  PARAMETER["num_row", 3], 
  PARAMETER["num_col", 3], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_0", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_0_2", 594520.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_1", -10.0], 
  PARAMETER["elt_1_2", 8625810.0]]


2021-04-21 17:02:05,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2021-04-21 17:02:05,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Producing the final mosaic, step 1, loop through granule collectors
2021-04-21 17:02:05,888 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Submosaic producer being called: org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector.DefaultSubmosaicProducer@1b928eaf
2021-04-21 17:02:05,889 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.granulecollector] - Adding to mosaic granule file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/data/data/DEMOS/ej_14_bands_zip/images/S2B_MSIL2A_20200715T140059_N0214_R067_T21LWG_20200715T162437_14BANDS.tif
2021-04-21 17:02:05,889 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Producing the final mosaic, step 2, final mosaicking
2021-04-21 17:02:05,889 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loaded bbox ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0] while crop bbox ReferencedEnvelope[594520.0 : 596140.0, 8623800.0 : 8625810.0]
2021-04-21 17:02:09,174 INFO [org.geoserver.wps] - 
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = myserver
    identifier:
        value = ras:CoverageClassStats
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@7fc7f125 (value: coverage, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@3f7de8c1 (body: net.opengis.wps10.impl.ExecuteTypeImpl@2732df58 (language: null, service: WPS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {}), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wps, method: POST, mimeType: image/tiff, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@7fcae23c (value: stats, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@3f446a39input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@6fafb6f0 (value: band, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@5ed67c42input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@76a5aea6 (value: classes, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@6aac07e9input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@7826347a (value: method, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@15ff6350
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@4ef43fd7 (value: results, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = text/xml
2021-04-21 17:02:09,179 INFO [org.vfny.geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
2021-04-21 17:02:09,179 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wps.WPSException: An error occurred while encoding the results of the process
    at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.writeComplex(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:229)
    at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.write(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:195)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1029)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
...


    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.wps.gs.ClassificationStatsPPIO.encode(ClassificationStatsPPIO.java:39)
    at org.geoserver.wps.XMLEncoderDelegate.encode(XMLEncoderDelegate.java:32)
    at org.geoserver.wps.response.ExecuteProcessResponse.writeComplex(ExecuteProcessResponse.java:225)
    ... 103 more
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: It looks like a problem with finding the max of the range (https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/770dc6f7023bc2ab32597cfc7a3a9cc35ff3b608/src/extension/wps/wps-core/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wps/gs/ClassificationStatsPPIO.java#L39) which is definitely a bug - can you file a bug report with enough info to allow someone to test it on the standard datasets if possible.

Comment: I tried to calculate raster stats with qgis to the ras:jiffle result tiff and gives me an error in Mean and Sum values: {'MAX': 0.9087093389296957,
'MEAN': nan,
'MIN': 0.17647058823529413,
'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': 'C:/Users/alexs/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_GXICtn/da1f3896ef7d46be94990d9b401c83ea/OUTPUT_HTML_FILE.html',
'RANGE': 0.7322387506944016,
'STD_DEV': 0.21709764069930515,
'SUM': nan,
'SUM_OF_SQUARES': 93.2730120968679} So I think the problem could be in jiffle process...